# customize older version of twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I know i can customize Bootstrap [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)

but I need some customization for version 2.1.1, where can I find `Customize and download` for it?

Comment: You could download the source of the version you need from their github here https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/tags

Comment: I need customization page for that version